# Playing video HTML5 and Apache

Tags: django, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

What I'd like to do is to play a video served by an request to a URL.
The webserver is Django

Here the HttpResponse to serve the video is formed:

```
filename = rec_path(recording_id) + '/rgb_video.mp4'
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='video/mp4')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=video.mp4'
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
return response
```

And in the HTML side I have

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src='{{ ROOT_URL}}/recordings/annotate/video/serve/{{ recording_id }}' type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag. //add this line
</video>
```

I can download the video but not play it this way. I've tried installing the mod_h264 mod
and configuring a simple VirtualHost that only serves files. I've also tried Jwplayer but none of them worked.

UPDATE: Strangely one of the videos play this way. All videos are produced with the same settings so I'm not sure what's causing this. The video that plays is quite short, 8 seconds, so perhaps that is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers play different formats natively.

Firefox 3.5+, Opera 10.5+ and Chrome 3+ support ogv
Firefox 4+, Opera 10.6+ and Chrome 6+ support WebM (and ogv)
Safari and IE support mp4

More [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-formats).

Which browser were you trying it in?

Comment: I'm tyring it in Chrome and the file type is mp4. I can download and play it, just not play via the html5 player (or any other player).